# How to bulk rename files numerically, in order of modification date?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, batch-rename, photo-management

I've got some photos with quite random names, but the dates (not exif, but when they were last edited) are correct. I'd like to rename them in that order, preferably so that the first photo is named `1.jpg` and so on, but anything goes.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you search for "rename" in the Ubuntu Software Center, you'll find several utilities that make it easy to bulk rename files. pyRenamer, Purrr, and GPRename are all great options.

Comment: Also KRename & GwenRename, if your desktop is KDE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the directory containing the pictures, run:

```
mkdir renamed; num=0; for f in $(ls -t); do cp -p "$f" renamed/IMG_$(printf "%03d" $num).jpg; num=$((num+1)); done
```

This will **copy** the files to a new directory `renamed`, keeping timestamps untouched. The format will be `IMG_###.jpg` with three-digit numbers, using leading zeros. You can change the number of digits by changing the `%03d` part.

Comment: Thanks! PS: If you want the oldest photo to have the lowest number and newest to have the last, then change `ls -t` to `ls -tr`

Comment: This will mess up if filenames have spaces etc. See [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2):

Try PyRenamer. I have just installed it and it seems very powerful. It allows you to rename your images based on their metadata.

Comment: You can use imagedate, but how do you use file metadata?